# Get node by Id in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have ids and I need to get the corresponding nodes.

But how ?

Here, "n" is my node id. How can i get the jstree object?

```
$.each(data.node.children,function(k,v){
 var n = $("#jstree_demo_div").find("[id='"+v+"']");
 console.log(n);
});
```

Regards.

Comment: `$("#jstree_demo_div").find("[id='"+v+"']")` is no different than `$('#'+v)`

Comment: unless this is invalid html and you are trying to find an ID within a child tree that isn't unique?

Answer (score 0):

To get the reference to the DOMElement you just need to call `.get(0)` on the jQuery object.

```
$.each(data.node.children,function(k,v){
 var n = $("#jstree_demo_div").find("[id='"+v+"']").get(0);
 console.log(n);
});
```

Unless you are working with invalid html, this can be shortened to the following:

```
$.each(data.node.children,function(k,v){
 var n = $('#'+v).get(0);
 console.log(n);
});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but that's what i need. I don't need a dom object but a jstree object.

Answer (score -2):

Solved.

I didn't have to get the node by id.

I get the JSON of the parent and find children.